# Python Dictionary: Return keys based on matching values in list

Tags: python, dictionary, data-science

I have a dictionary wherein the key is a unique name and the value is a list of non-unique names.
For domain knowledge sake, the keys are Tableau workbooks and the value is a list of tables the workbook connects to.

What I am trying to do is return, for each key, every other key that has at least three matching values. Doing so will basically allow me to find workbooks that are overlapping data by using the same tables.

Currently, I am able to find all keys that match a specific value by doing the following:

```
keys = [key for key, value in intersect_dict.items() if 'VOLUME_DIMENSION' in value]
keys

values = [value for key, value in intersect_dict.items() if 'VOLUME_DIMENSION' in value]
values
```

The output of keys is:

```
['(SAN) STORAGE GROUP INVENTORY AND CAPACITY',
 '(SAN) STORAGE GROUP INVENTORY AND CAPACITY V2',
 'SAN INVENTORY AND CAPACITY']
```

And the output of values is:

```
[['VOLUME_DIMENSION',
  'EXTENDED_DATA',
  'VOLUME_HISTORY_CAPACITY_FACT',
  'HOST_DIMENSION',
  'STORAGE_DIMENSION',
  'DATE_DIMENSION'],
 ['STORAGE_DIMENSION',
  'DATE_DIMENSION',
  'VOLUME_DIMENSION',
  'HOST_DIMENSION',
  'VOLUME_HISTORY_CAPACITY_FACT',
  'EXTENDED_DATA'],
 ['VOLUME_HISTORY_CAPACITY_FACT',
  'HOST_DIMENSION',
  'EXTENDED_DATA',
  'DATE_DIMENSION',
  'STORAGE_DIMENSION',
  'VOLUME_DIMENSION']]
```

Is there a possible way that I can do essentially the same thing except instead of

`if 'VOLUME_DIMENSION' in value` I have `if values in value match 3 times or more`?

Please let me know if more info is needed.

Edit1: Below is the input dictionary excerpt requested:

```
{'(SAN) STORAGE GROUP INVENTORY AND CAPACITY': ['VOLUME_DIMENSION',
  'EXTENDED_DATA',
  'VOLUME_HISTORY_CAPACITY_FACT',
  'HOST_DIMENSION',
  'STORAGE_DIMENSION',
  'DATE_DIMENSION'],
 '(SAN) STORAGE GROUP INVENTORY AND CAPACITY V2': ['STORAGE_DIMENSION',
  'DATE_DIMENSION',
  'VOLUME_DIMENSION',
  'HOST_DIMENSION',
  'VOLUME_HISTORY_CAPACITY_FACT',
  'EXTENDED_DATA'],
```

The requested output would be something like:

```
{'(SAN) STORAGE GROUP INVENTORY AND CAPACITY': workbook1, workbook7, workbook8}
```

The "workbooks" shown as values would be the workbooks who have three or more matching values with that key.

Edit2: Sorry for bad data format explanation. Attempting to clarify that here.

```
d = { 
    'item1': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 
    'item2': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 
    'item3': ['A', 'C', 'D'], 
    'item4': ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 
    'item5': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 
    'item6': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'E'], 
    }

Results = { 
    'item1': ['item2', 'item5', 'item6'] 
    'item2': ['item1', 'item5', 'item6'] 
    }
```

In the above example, d would be my overall dataset in dictionary form and Results are what I would like for the output to be. So it would let me target which items are sharing data. Or in this case, sharing letters.

Comment: could you share an excerpt of `intersect_dict`?

Comment: It's doable, but it's hard to give an exact answer without example input and desired output. Please [edit] the question to add details. See [ask] and [mre] for advice.

Comment: @mrzo Sorry, had some formatting issues in the comment lol, added it to the post!

wjandrea, Apologies for the lack of info, I added some examples to the post! Please let me know if that is not enough.

Comment: No need to apologize :) What are some example values of `workbook1, workbook7, workbook8`?

Comment: @wjandrea So they might be things like '(SAN) STORAGE GROUP INVENTORY AND CAPACITY'

Maybe there is, for example, multiple versions of that workbook that have a version tag at the end. 

So we have the original above then workbook1,7,etc would be '(SAN) STORAGE GROUP INVENTORY AND CAPACITY V2', '(SAN) STORAGE GROUP INVENTORY AND CAPACITY V3' and so on.

Comment: @NTWorthy But that's the name of that workbook. Of course it overlaps with itself... It would really help if you made a concrete example. Also your data's really verbose, so it would help to use example data like in mrzo's answer.

Comment: Sorry.. trying to think of a textual way to explain this is hard lol. I think I explained it a little better in a reply to mrzo's answer.. though comment formatting is not the best lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `set`:

```
d = {
    'item1': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'item2': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    'item3': ['A', 'C', 'D'],
    'item4': ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
}

search_items = {'A', 'B', 'C'}
keys = [key for key, value in d.items() if len(search_items & set(value)) >= 3]
print(keys)

values = [value for key, value in d.items() if len(search_items & set(value)) >= 3]
print(values)
```

Output:

```
['item1', 'item2']
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]
```

To get all keys that share three or more items, you can do:

```
common_items = [
    (search_key, key, set(search_values) & set(values))
    for search_key, search_values in d.items()
    for key, values in d.items()
    if search_key != key and len(set(search_values) & set(values)) >= 3
]
print(common_items)
```

```
[('item1', 'item2', {'C', 'B', 'A'}),
 ('item2', 'item1', {'C', 'B', 'A'}),
 ('item2', 'item3', {'C', 'D', 'A'}),
 ('item2', 'item4', {'C', 'D', 'B'}),
 ('item3', 'item2', {'C', 'D', 'A'}),
 ('item4', 'item2', {'C', 'D', 'B'})]
```

Comment: Okay, I think I'm understanding that. Could I replace the value of search_items with say.. a list of all possible table names/values maybe? Then in theory it would find all matches that share 3 tables right? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: See my edit. This still contains duplicates but basically gives you all key pairs that share three or more items together. Is that what you need?

Comment: It's closer. But using your data examples, what I'm looking for would be more like so:


**d = {
    'item1': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'item2': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    'item3': ['A', 'C', 'D'],
    'item4': ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
    'item5': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'item6': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'E'],
}**


**Results = {
    'item1': ['item2', 'item5', 'item6']
    'item2': ['item1', 'item5', 'item6']
}**

So from this we could glean that items1, 2, 5, and 6 have overlap because they all contain 'A', 'B' and 'C'. Does that make sense?

Comment: I had to make a slight modification to your answer, but it ended up giving me the result I wanted. 

I took away the ", set(search_values) & set(values)" portion of common items.
This gave me a list of lists of tuples. Doing some pandas magic, I got a dataframe where one column was the item name then the second column was every item that matched 3 or more values. Thanks so much for your guidance on this! We got it done. :)